# Is there a way to not make the Comment (suggestion) box disappear if you accept or discard it?

Tags: text, ckeditor, text-editor, rich-text-editor

When I insert a comment and select accept/discard, the comment disappears.

Additionally, when I assign a comment (@name), is there a way to ensure only the assigned person actually accepts/discards the comment?

We have not found a solution and had some confusion through support@CKE.

Can anyone share some creative ideas with the comment (suggestions)?

I was looking to have the comment feature be:

- poll-like with binary choices
- memorialize decision
- ability to direct to person/people to decide on

Thanks!